# how can i manage phonegap android online app

Tags: android, cordova

i'm beginner developer of phonegap android application developer. i'm in confusion. i want to make a photo gallery that work online(with internet). 1st: how can i embed my photo gallery with the application. 2nd: if user connection lost during checking photos there is not show the my app url (could not find URL http://www.domain.com/app/index.php) after connection lost it will go to on default error page of no internet connection.

my online application is in php how can i iframe that app in my native application.

phonegap android application developer help me. i'm very thankful to you for this.

Comment: have you tried anything or done any research?

Comment: yes i search but didn't find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phonegap is not really a way to embed a full application inside an app. The app itself is its own website (sort of).

Your best direction is to create a PHP page on your sever that outputs an XML or JSON file of the images you are going to show THEN create a custom application using HTML / Javascript that  pulls in the XML/JSON and parses it into your app. For best practise you should cache or store  said files locally for when the device isn't connected to the network.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i want to upload a huge collection of image data. There is no possibilities for local storage. is there any possibility cos i'm beginner developer of php. i'm not know about how to create xml output and JSON?